# Why z=f(x) does not imply E[z]=f(E[x]) when f is not linear?

Tags: self-study, expected-value

Why $z=f(x)$ does not imply $E[z]=f(E[x])$ when f is not linear?

I can give an example, but I couldn't derive the general form.

Let $z = {x^2}$

Let $g(x)$ be the pdf of $x$. Then:

$ E\left[ z \right] = E\left[ {{x^2}} \right] = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\left( {{x^2}} \right)g\left( x \right)dx} $

$f\left( {E\left[ x \right]} \right) = {\left( {\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\left( x \right)g\left( x \right)dx} } \right)^2}$

$ \Rightarrow E\left[ z \right] \ne f\left( {E\left[ x \right]} \right)$

Comment: It is slightly difficult to understand the question, but consider $X$ uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$ and $f(x)=x^3$.  You have $(E[X])^3 = 0 = E[X^3].$

Comment: [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) is basically what you are looking for.

Comment: @Tim Why not posting this as an answer? Please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically looking for the [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). Proofs are in the article.